# How to get a total cost with adding the prices for things?

Tags: python

Here is my code and you also run it here: https://repl.it/repls/MonumentalViciousMamba

```
available_things=["bike","smart tv","car","i-phone X"]
prices=[100,150,180,300] 
additionals=["smart phone","xbox","ps4","laptop","chromebook"]

things=raw_input("\nWhat you wish to get:")
selected_additionals=[]
for val in range(0,3):
    selected_additionals.append(raw_input("Note: You will be charged $20 for each additional item. Please enter an additional item:"))

for selected_additional in selected_additionals: 
    if selected_additional not in additionals and selected_additional != "":
        print("\nSorry we don't have "+str(selected_additional)+"\nBut we will change it to a gift. Note the gift also charges $20") 

if size in availablePizzas:
    print("Your total cost is: $"+str(pizzaPrice+2))
```

I want to get the price for bike =100, smart tv =150, car =150, and iphone-X =300. My last two lines prints out the last price in the prices list which is 300 for every available things I input.

Comment: So where is the problem? What is the output? No other hints? Just throw the code to us solve for you?

Comment: I can't provide output here because it needs you to enter inputs. You can check the output in the link I provided.

Comment: My problem is, it prints out the last price in the prices list for my last two lines of codes.

Comment: I want like to get the price for bike =100, smart tv =150, car =150, and iphone-X =300.

Comment: For example if they selected bike they are charged with 100 plus each item they selected including gift.

Comment: You should add explanations in your question not as comments!

Comment: i am sorry i will edit my question

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, it was far more clear before editing. However, according to your first explanation, your code should be something like:

```
available_things=['bike','smart tv', 'car', 'i-phone X']
prices=[100,150,180,300] 
additionals=['smart phone', 'xbox', 'ps4' , 'laptop', 'chromebook']

selected_additionals= [str(i) for i in raw_input("What you wish to get:").split()] # making a list of items which user inserts
#selected_additionals = ['bike', 'X', 'car'] # here I expect $100 + $180 + $20 = $300 as output

Totalprice = []
for i in selected_additionals: 
    if i in available_things: # comparing 2 lists
        Totalprice.append(prices[available_things.index(i)])
    else:
        Totalprice.append(20) #charge $20 on each item which is not in the avaialable_things

print sum(Totalprice)
```

I assumed you're using Python 2, for python 3 you should use `input()`